# TP-Link Archer T3U Plus doesn't work

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I tried everything that I found .. although I have no idea what I actually did. I just copy the lines in the answers .. but nothing worked.

PLEASE WRITE AN INSTRUCTION FOR IDIOTS

I'm not a dumb person .. but when it comes to Linux I really feel like it :/

lsusb: Bus 001 Device 014: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC

The hardware is seen but it doesn't work

The old TP-link just worked without doing anything.

- Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64
- bits: 64
- Desktop: Gnome 3.36.7
- Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Network: Message:

`No Device data found. Device-1: TP-Link 802.11ac NIC type: USB driver: usb-network`

- dkms, modprobe and make doesn't work
- rfkill shows that wlan isn't blocked when I use the old device
- rfkill shows no wlan at all when I use the new TP-link

Please help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms bc
sudo git clone "https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git" /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git
sudo sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION="@PKGVER@"/PACKAGE_VERSION="git"/g' /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git/dkms.conf
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v git
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

You may safely copy and paste each command and execute them one at a time. Remove and reinsert your USB wireless and it should now be working.

Comment: it works!!! thank you!!